# PHP .htaccess with two parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

Right now I have a multilingual CMS and it's working great with .htaccess.

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#redirect lang
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Now my link:

```
www.mywebsite.com/team.php?lang=en
```

acts as

```
www.mywebsite.com/en/team
```

That's OK.

The first issue is: 
I've created a language switcher that has a links `?lang=en`, `?lang=de` and when I click on German, the link becomes

```
www.mywebsite.com/en/team?lang=de
```

This is invalid and it doesn't change the language.

How can I set the language switcher to change the language on German, so this URL:

```
www.mywebsite.com/en/team
```

to become

```
www.mywebsite.com/de/team
```

The second issue:
I have a pages like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/team-view?id=1
www.mywebsite.com/team-view?id=2
www.mywebsite.com/team-view?id=3
```

and so on. When I add another parameter `lang=en`

so they become

```
www.mywebsite.com/team-view?id=1&lang=en
```

This is valid and it shows the English content, but how can I set the .htaccess with two parameters?

I want this link to become

```
www.mywebsite.com/en/team-view/1
```

Also the language switcher to change the language properly, so to be like this when I choose German language:

```
www.mywebsite.com/de/team-view/1
```

Comment: When using a `.htaccess` to rewrite URLs like this, you need to use what the rewritten URL will be as the href in your links. For example, your language switcher links should be `/en/{page}` and `/de/{page}` instead of the `?lang=` that you have now

Comment: Also, for your second issue, this might help you test different htaccess files - http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/